# Change image source according to screen size via data attribute in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How we can change image source according to screen size in angular js via data attribute. Please suggest appropriate approach in angular js.

```
  <img src="abc.jpg" data-desktop="abc.jpg" data-tablet="xyz.png" data-mobile="bcd.jpg" >
```

Comment: A directive on the element that set its source based on the screen size

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a custom directive.  See working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7oVbjaK0QQPHGjyWzfrA?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<img src="default.jpg" small="small.jpg" big="big.jpg" change-on-screen-resize />
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive("changeOnScreenResize", ["$window", function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      $window.onresize = function() {
        changeImage();
        scope.$apply();
      }

      //no such method 'on' for $window
      //$window.on('resize', function(){
      //});

      changeImage();

      function changeImage() {
        var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;

        if(screenWidth <= 400) {
          //attrs.src = attrs.small;
          elem.attr('src', attrs.small);
        } else {
          elem.attr('src', attrs.big);
        }
      }
    }
  };
}])
```

Comment: lets do `$window.on('resize', handleFn)`, because `onresize ` function does override the old registered re-size event(not good practice), Though +1

Comment: it is not working here is my codepen [link](http://codepen.io/satnam348/pen/YqdNOZ)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to set src using `attrs.src` which, aparently, isn't the way.  See edit and working Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/7oVbjaK0QQPHGjyWzfrA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using src="..." you could use ng-src=someFunctionInYourController() to return the appropriate image file name.

If you're using Bootstrap, Angular Material, etc. there are directives you can use to display content based on media queries. Also AngularMaterial has the $mdMedia service that can help you with this.

Comment: No, but the code in the directive that was posted above could be adapted to a function in your controller easily. That being said, the directive route is the way to go.